# Правильное написание слова

Tags: орфография

"Недорого" или "не дорого"?

Answer (score 2):

Вещь стоила недорого (дёшево)-утверждает, что недорого, можно заменить синонимом.

Что Вы, это не дорого, а дёшево. Это вовсе не дорого. Не дорого ли? - отрицает, что дорого. Есть или подразумевается противопоставление.

Answer (score 0):

НЕДОРОГО - наречие (сколько?).                Наречия на -о-е пишутся с НЕ-
1)  слитно, если слово без НЕ не употребляется (Написано небрежно)
2)  слитно, если слово можно заменить синонимом без НЕ.(Этот товар стоит недорого (=дёшево))
3)  раздельно, если есть слова (вовсе, далеко, отнюдь) или слова с приставкой НИ-.(Ничуть не дорого стоит эта вещь. Нисколько не дорого обойдется нам поездка к морю)
4)  раздельно, если есть противопоставление с союзом а. (Она стоит не дорого, а вполне приемлемо)
Все перечисленные пункты правила относятся и к краткому прилагательному, 
если НЕДОРОГО является таковым. Например, платье (каково?) – недорого(кр. прил.)